# Attaching click event only to the row, not the links

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML table where I've attached a click event to its rows where once a row is clicked, the "active" class is toggled (added and removed).

There are links inside this table that have their own click events attached.

Is there a way to prevent those links click events from toggling the row class?

```
$("table tbody tr").on("click", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

$("table tbody a").on("click", function(){
    //do something else but don't toggle the active class
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `stopPropagation()` on the `a` click event to prevent it propagating up the DOM to the parent `tr`:

```
$("table tbody a").on("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  // do something 
});
```